# Настройка Help Page для ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, документация, formdata

Делаю для своего WepAbpi сервера документацию.
Поскольку требуется просто базовое описание, решил использовать стандартный функционал от Microsoft для создания Help Page.
Установил, разобрался, все настроил, все работает.
Кроме одного момента.
Сейчас, она показывает какую модель(класс) ожидает мой Контроллер, если модель передается, как body параметр(как аргумент в контроллере). Но как сгенерировать описание модели(класса), если данные для нее приходят, не как аргумент контроллера, а как данные multipart/form-data. Т.е. внутри контролла я создаю модель, через HttpContext:

```
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
var formContent = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;

ModelWhatNeededDocumentation modlel = new ModelWhatNeededDocumentation() { param1= formContent["param11"], param2 = formContent["param22"]};
```

Так же на странице помощи есть авто-сгенерированный Sample для того запроса с формы, который ожидает мой контроллер. Вот его бы неплохо то же было бы подстроить под мою ModelWhatNeededDocumentation.

Comment: сюда посмотри https://swagger.io/

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но это не особо помогло. Я все еще не могу найти информацию, как добавить модель, ожидаемую в HttpContext в документацию.